# PHP not executing in .INC file

Tags: php, jquery, include

Not quite sure if 'php' has anything to do with it. please review http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/#press

I have a default tab on my page that displays 2 blog posts sorted by date.
but it wont show up when I click back to it in the menu, I have it included
in two separate places, is there an easier way to achieve this?? I know there is

```
<?php
    // Include WordPress
    define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
    require('/home/whiteb0x/iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/blog/wp-blog-header.php');
    query_posts('cat=3&showposts=2');
?>

        <article class="blog-feed">
<?php while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
<!-- begin post -->
            <div class="blog-title">
                <div class="blog-date">
                <?php the_time('m.j.Y'); ?>
                </div>
            <strong><a class="blog-link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"> 
<?php the_title(); ?>
                </a></strong> 
            </div>  
<a class="blog-link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"> 
<div class="blog-thumbnail"><?php the_post_thumbnail( array(80,80) ); ?></div><?php the_content(); ?>
</a>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
        </article>
```

```
   <?php
        // Include WordPress
        define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
        require('/home/whiteb0x/iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/blog/wp-blog-header.php');
        query_posts('cat=3&showposts=2');
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html> 
    <head></head>
    <body>

        <ul>
            <li id="current_news">
    <?php
    echo "HELLO";
    ?>
    **<?php 
        require('post.inc')
    ?>**
```

Comment: change your filename to `post.inc.php`

Comment: ok one sec I tried that before and then I got weird behavior such as every link in the menu loading the same #anchor in my document

Answer (score 3):

Does `post.inc` start with a `<?php`?

It's important that your include file have that if you want your code to execute when you include.